# Store Image in realm data base

Tags: java, android, database, android-studio, realm

As the title show,I have an app that has people information,the information include people names,ages,jobs,id and images.
So I want to store the images in realm database or store the images path in database, put I don't know the right way to do that.

So anyone have a tutorial or an example to do that.`

this is my DataBase Model:

```
    public class People extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private String name;
    private byte[] image;
    private String job;

    public Authors() {
    }

    public Authors(byte[]  image, String job, String name) {
        this.image = image;
        this.job = job;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public byte[]  getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(byte[]  image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getJob() {
        return job;
    }

    public void setJob(String job) {
        this.job = job;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

This is an image for what i want to do:

[image: the screenshot]

Answer (score 4):

Do not store raw image. Just store URL you downloaded image from in `String` format.

```
...
private String image;
...
public String  getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(String  image) {
    this.image = image;
}
...
```

And the right way to load, display, cache images is to use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

Comment: Can I use this method for offline applications ?

Comment: @AhmedEzzat for offline application you need to maintain a copy of image in local storage and save the path/uri in the realm database.